# Python: how many process can access to Database(PostgreSQL) table at the same time?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, multiprocessing

This is the simplified version of my code, at which each process crawl the link and get data and store them in database in parallel.

```
def crawl_and_save_data(url):
    while True:
        res = requests.get(url)
        price_list = res.json()

        if len(price_list) == 0:
            sys.exit()

        # Save all datas in DB HERE
        # for price in price_list:
        #    Save price in PostgreSQL Database table (same table)

        until_date = convert_date_format(price_list[len(price_list)-1]['candleDateTime'])
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__=='__main__':
    # When executed with pure python
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(
        crawl_and_save_data, 
        get_bunch_of_url_list()
    )
```

The key point of this code is,

```
# Save all data in DB HERE
# for price in price_list:
#    Save price in PostgreSQL Database table (same table)
```

, where each process accesses same database table.

I wonder whether this kind of task prevents concurrency of my whole task.

Or, Would it be a possibility to lose data because of the concurrent database accesses?

Or, would all queries are put in a I/O queue or something?

Need your advices. Thanks

Comment: Depends on what the function does. Generally speaking, database are pretty good at handling concurrency, if you use them properly.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, above code are all functions that this program use. What is the meaning of "use them properly"..?

Comment: I mean, what does `requests.get` and `convert_date_format` do on the database? You need to know the SQL statements.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe just ignore that statement. Focus on what I wrote as "The key point of this code is" part

Comment: I focused and saw only three lines of comment. How should this question be answered without knowing these details?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr - you should be fine, but the question doesn't include enough detail to answer definitively. You will need to run some tests, but you should expect to get a good amount of concurrency (a few dozen simultaneous writes) before things start to slow down.

Note though - as currently written, seems like your workers will get the same URL over and over again, because of the `while True` loop that never breaks or exits. You detect if the list is empty, but does the URL track state somehow? I would expect multiple, identical GETs to return the same data over and over...

As far as concurrency, that ultimately depends on -

- The resources available to the database (memory, I/O, CPU)
- The server-side resources consumed by each connection/operation.

That second point includes memory, etc., but also whether independent
operations are competing for the same resources (are 10 different connections
trying to update the same set of rows in the database?). Updating the same
table is fine, more or less, because the database can use row-level locks.

Also note the difference between concurrency (how many things happen at
once) and throughput (how many things happen within a period of time).
Concurrency and throughput can relate to each in counter-intuitive ways -
it's not uncommon to see a situation where 1 process can do N operations per
second, but M processes sustain *far less* than M x N operations per second,
possibly even bringing the whole thing to a screeching halt (e.g., via a
deadlock)

Thinking about your code snippet, here are some observations:

- You are using `multiprocessing.Pool`, which uses sub-processes for concurrency and will work well for your case if you...
- Make sure you open your connections in the sub-process; trying to re-use a connection from the parent process will not work
- If you do nothing else to your code, you will be using a number of sub-processes equal to the number of cores on your db client machine

  - This is a good starting point. If a function is CPU-bound, you really can't go higher. If your function is I/O-bound, the CPU will be idle waiting for I/O operations to return. You can start ramping up the worker count in this case.
- Thus, each sub-process will have a connection to the database, with some amount of server memory per connection.
- This also means that each insert should be in isolated transactions, with no additional work on your part.

Given that, simple, append-only, row-by-row transactions should support
relatively high concurrency *and* high throughput, again depending on how
big and fast your DB server is.

Also, note that you are already queueing :) With no args, `Pool()` creates a
number of child processes equal to `os.cpu_count()` (see
the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)).
If that's greater than the number of URLs in your collection, that collection
is a queue of sorts, just not a durable one. If your master process dies, the
list of URLs is gone.

Unrelated - unless you are worried about your URL fetches getting throttled, from a db perspective, there is no need for the `time.sleep(1)` statement.

Hope this helps.